# Поиск в SQLite и вывод в ListFragment

Tags: android-fragment, android, cursoradaper

На активити есть 2 фрагмента:

1. `SearchFragment`: строка поиска и кнопка.
2. `ListFragment` с результатами поиска.

При нажатии на кнопку из `SearchFragment` через callback запускается метод в активити.
Дальше нужно найти список `items` из SQLite и вывести в `ListFragment`.
Поиск вынесен в метод отдельного класса `DBHelper.SearchItems(String searchString)`.

Не могу сообразить, что и в каких местах нужно делать: из активити производить поиск, получать cursor и его передавать в `listFragment` или в `listFragment` передавать строку поиска, искать в фрагменте?

Comment: В DBHelper добавить функцию прослушивания и подписаться на нее в ListFragment. При поиске из SearchFragment вызывать SearchItems, а оттуда отправлять результат всем подписавшимся.

Comment: Я счита, что искать нужно в ListFragment, а не в Activity. Если, конечно полученные данные запроса будут использоваться только в этом ListFragment. У фрагмена есть все необходимые хуки, чтобы корректно инициализировать и уничтожить вовремя курсор. Активность не будет перегружена ненужным кодом.
Этот ListFragment можно будет повторно использовать с этим поиском.
Возможно даже, будет смысл вынести курсор в retained fragment, либо использовать loader'ы, чтобы корректно его сохранить при поворотах экрана.

Comment: Первоначально listFragment не добавлен на активити, соответственно слушать некому. Во всех книгах поиск реализуют в onCreate, но ищут по всей базе. Как тогда передать туда поисковую фразу?

Comment: Создал синглетный класс со строкой запроса и ссылкой на Бд. Поиск в onCreate